# ¿Se puede enviar un objeto como parámetro por medio de VUE Router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, routerlink, params

Lo que quiero lograr es mandar un objeto(Estoy recorriendo con la directiva v-for) de mi componente a otro componente por medio de router-link.
1.- La vista donde recorro el objeto productos quiero enviar ese producto a una vista detalle.

```
 <template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Productos</h1>
    <div class="productos-container">
      <div
        class="card"
        style="width: 18rem"
        v-for="item in productos"
        :key="item"
      >
        <img
          src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100/O https://placeholder.com/"
          class="card-img-top"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.titulo }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            {{ item.description }}
          </p>
          <router-link :to="{name:'Producto', params:{producto: item} }" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Ver detalle</router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

2.- La vista donde quiero recibir mi objeto item.

```
 <div class="container">

<div class="productos-container">
  <div
    class="card"
    style="width: 18rem"
  >
    <img
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100/O https://placeholder.com/"
      class="card-img-top"
    />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">asd</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        lorem
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3.- Ruta del componente detalle aqui:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/producto/:producto', name: 'Producto', props: true, component: () => import('../views/productos/Detalle.vue') }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow.ES!

En tu caso, la respuestas es muy sencilla, debes añadir al componente donde deseas abrir un objeto la propiedad `props`, que te permite indicar en el componente B, lo que A va a mandarle, tanto el nombre como el tipo.

En tu caso, sería algo así:

```
  props: {
    producto: Object,
  },
```

Y con eso, ya tendrías acceso a tu objeto `producto` en el componente B.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu aportación, ya lo intente de la manera en la que me indicas sin embargo al recibir la variable 'producto' en mi componente detalle llega como [object object] sin ningún dato

Answer (score 0):

Estás pasando el objeto en los parámetros, es decir, se guarda en `this.$route.params.producto`, lo que te falta es asignarlo a una variable y listo, desde ahí lo utilizas.

Ejemplo en el componente a visualizar:

```
mounted () {
    this.productoTraido = this.$route.params.producto;
}
```